# show sql query progress in php/mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, csv

I am running some sql queries on mysql from php, First I am submitting a csv file from a html form then I read the first column from csv file. For every row in csv I am making a mysql query.

```
    <form action="updateTrackingStatus.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" required/>
            <BR /><BR />
            <input type="submit" id="upload" name="submit" title="Upload" class="submitButton"/>
    </form>
```

Untill all the queries are finished the page loads in the browser and after that goes to the `updateTrackingStatus.php` page. How can I show the    progress or number of rows updated on current page(page which have form).

If my csv file is big it loads for long time so I want to show progress bar to the users.

Answer (score 1):

One way will be to use Ajax.
You can submit the file with Ajax, using jQuery or something else.
Then in your process file put the information in log file and read it trough other Ajax.

1. Submit form trough Ajax with random parameter: &var={timestamp}
2. Put information about the progress in a file with filename equal to &var value. All form plugins for jQuery has function for progress, there you can read the progress from the file. you can place the file in your public folder and just get it's content with jQuery.get().
3. Read the information about the progress with Ajax on the page where you submitted the form.

Example helper file structure:
12345\n (total rows)
23\n (current row)

More readable but slower way is JSON:
{"all": 21345, "current": 23}

And make sure you overwrite the file every time and delete it after process is complete.